# spinner in android xml layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, spinner

I'm trying to design a layout for an android app.
this is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/nameFB"
    android:layout_gravity="end" />

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="end">

        <Spinner

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:text="@string/type_string" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/yearTextName"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_style"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:text="@string/year_string" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/creatorTextName"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_style"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:text="@string/creator_string" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/nameTextBox"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_style"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:text="@string/name_string" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_search_results"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and it looks like this:

[image]

but when I add an id value for the spinner:

```
<Spinner
            android:id="@+id/a"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

for some reason it ruins the layout:

[image]

Does anyone know why does it happen? The only thing I'm changing is a value of an id, not something graphic.
How can I fix it? Or how can I rearrange the xml so that the text boxes and the spinner will be visible with the text views (maybe in two rows)? I tried to put to linear layout one after the other and put in them the widgets, but every time it looks like the second picture.

Answer (score 0):

I am still searching the reason behind this behavior.

But for the time being , you can use below code for your layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/nameFB"/>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/adsa"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="type"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/yearTextName"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="year"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/creatorTextName"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="craetor"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/nameTextBox"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="name"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_search_results"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

You can modify the weights for views according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you in this situation you should change your design. Spinner keep in a single row and rest of the control keep in second row.